# Image intervention сохраняет в повернутом виде

Tags: php

```
$image = new ImageManager();

$img = $image->make("/img.jpg")->resize("300", null, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});
$img->save("/new_img.jpg");
```

Если загружать фото с телефона, где фото автоматически поворачивается в зависимости от ориентации экрана, то при загрузке на сайт и прохождение через библиотеку [ImageManager](http://image.intervention.io/api/resize), оно остается развернутым.

Comment: Ваш код не учитывает свойства изображения, хранящиеся в EXIF заголовке. Для правильной ориентации с помощью этой библиотеки добавьте вызов к [orientate](https://medium.com/thetiltblog/fixing-rotated-mobile-image-uploads-in-php-803bb96a852c) методу. Также убедитесь что PHP скомпилировано с флагом —enable-exif.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov спасибо, ваш ответ помог! Можете написать ответ полноценный, я сделаю его как решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код не учитывает свойства изображения, хранящиеся в EXIF заголовке. Для правильной ориентации с помощью этой библиотеки добавьте вызов к [orientate](https://medium.com/thetiltblog/fixing-rotated-mobile-image-uploads-in-php-803bb96a852c) методу. Также убедитесь что PHP скомпилировано с флагом —enable-exif